# ASP.NET MVC How-to use routes when application is published as SubProject of a domain?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, subproject

i have a webapp which works perfectly when debugged and tested locally. However when I publish the site to a productionserver the routing is messed up. This is because it runs as a sub-project on the productionserver.

```
Testing:     http://localhost:xxx/
Production:  http://remotehost/webapp/
```

**How should I setup routing?**

This is my current routing setup (mostly default). The server displays the default Controller action when I visit http://remotehost/webapp/. But when I hard-code the controller (http://remotehost/webapp/Project/ it doesn't work...

```
Shared Sub RegisterRoutes(ByVal routes As RouteCollection)
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}")

    routes.MapRoute("ProjectsByCategory", "Project/Category/{id}", _
                    New With {.controller = "Project", .action = "ListByCategory", .id = ""}, _
                    New With {.id = "^[0-9]+"})


    routes.MapRoute( _
        "Default", _
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", _
        New With {.controller = "Project", .action = "Index", .id = ""} _
    )

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it sounds like it might be related to publishing on iis 6. There's an article [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) about that.

For me a similar problem was resolved by adding a 'Wildcard application map':

- In IIS, right click and choose Properties for the virtual directory in question
- choose Virtual directory tab
- choose Configuration
- click Insert
- enter the path to aspnet-isapi.dll (typically c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll).

Comment: I had the application running as virtual directory, not application. And I also needed to add wildcard mapping for the rewriting of the urls. Thx

Answer (score 0):

By the way, the routing seems to be working on application level. No need to bother your domainname or higher directory names.